# How to remove the 'Reply' link in comments?

Tags: 7, theming, comments

I'm currently using the following line of code in my `comment.tpl.php` file:

```
<?php print render($content['links']) ?>
```

This also prints the 'Reply' link, but I'd like to remove that one. How can I do that?

---

**Note:** I'm able to hide the 'Reply' link with CSS, but that's not a very nice solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to remove all links, you could do it in a template file like this:

```
hide($content['links']);
print render($content);
```

But I don't know how to hide just the comment reply link this way. Based on a short article [here](http://timonweb.com/how-remove-reply-link-drupal-7-comments), it looks like you can unset the reply link with a preprocess function in template.php like this:

```
function themename_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  unset($variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']);
}
```

Comment: I expected that the problem could be solved within the template file, but this preprocess function works all the same. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to change this behavior by modifying the `comment settings` for each content-type. This could be done by going into `admin/structure/types/manage/<your-content-type>`, scroll down and click on `comment settings` in the left menu. In the settings form you then uncheck the box next to `Show reply form on the same page as comments`.

[image: Comment Settings]

The above doesn't seems to work, but you could easily make a small module and implement `hook_comment_view()`:

```
function <YOURMODULE>_comment_view($comment, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  unset($comment->content['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I unchecked the box you mentioned, but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Jeroen - I noticed that the above didn't do what I expected and therefore updated my answer with a working solution.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and update! Is working with `hook_comment_view` more appropriate than `hook_preprocess_comment` according to you? I'm not an expert in these kind of things...

Comment: No, I think both will work. The only thing was that I couldn't get `hook_comment_view()` to work in the theme so I was forced to add it into a small custom module. If you are able to use `hook_preprocess_comment()` in your template file I would stick with that.